# IDLE is returning the '=== RESTART ===' line but no other output

Tags: python, python-idle

```
import random
gCount = 1
pChoice = ("sdq")
while gCount == 10 or pChoice == ("q"):
pChoice = input("Steal, Deal or Quit [s|d|q]?")
if pChoice != ("q"):
    gCount += 1
    print("Jackpot:100")

#Determing and displaying choice
    if pChoice == ("s"):
        print("C: Steal")
    elif pChoice == ("d"):
        print ("C: Deal")

#Determing and displaying computer choice
    cChoice= random.randint(1,2)
    if cChoice == 1:
        print("Comp:Steal")
    elif cChoice == 2:
        print("Comp:Deal")

#Determining and displaying whether the player wins or loses, as well as scores
# for that round.
    if pChoice == ("s") and cChoice == 1:
        print("S:   0       |       0")
        print("You lose! You get nothing!")
    elif pChoice == ("d") and cChoice == 1:
        print("S:   0       |       100")
        print("You lose! You get nothing!")
    elif pChoice == ("d") and cChoice == 2:
        print("S:   50      |       50")
        print("Draw! Split pot!")
    else:
        print("S:   100     |       0")
        print("You win! Jackpot!")
```

This code is returning

```
================================ RESTART ================================
```

when run in the IDLE terminal. I'm unsure as to what is causing this.

```
Python 3.4.3
32-bit IDLE for 3.4.3
Windows 7 64-bit
```

Comment: Is it literally only returning RESTART and nothing before or after it?

Comment: Is this your exact actual code? You have an indentation error on the line after your first `while`.

Comment: How do you run the script in IDLE?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the indentation of your code is like this (otherwise it would be a syntax error):

```
import random
gCount = 1
pChoice = ("sdq")
while gCount == 10 or pChoice == ("q"):
    # everything else here
```

Then your script does exactly nothing. `gCount` is `1`, so `gCount == 10` will never be true, as such nothing in your loop runs, and there is no output otherwise.

So the `RESTART` line just says that the IDLE interpreter reset itself, then ran your script (resulting in no output), and then it’s over.

Comment: You beat me to it. The code never enters the loop because `("sdq") == ("q")` is also `False`.

Comment: Whoops, I'm an idiot :). It should be `pChoice !="q"`